# Get rid of lingering file found with `lsof +L1`

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, pulseaudio, disk, lsof

`Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

Hi,
I had a large database file that filled up my disk space and I deleted it with `rm big-file`.

Then when I wanted to install something (the CLion backend via SSH) I got the prompt that the system had not enough disk space.
`df -h` shows that I should have 69G free fisk space on my main disk.
Running `sudo lsof +L1` tells me, that the command `pulseaudi` is holding on to a huge file (around the 69G I am looking for...).

I tried killing puleaudio, it kept respawning.
I then disabled the system service from respawning it, which gave me another suprising result.
Running `sudo lsof +L1` now displays:

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK     NODE NAME
Xorg      1854  ipc   36u   REG    0,1        4     0     3081 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg      1854  ipc   48u   REG    0,1        4     0     1035 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg      1854  ipc   49u   REG    0,1        4     0     3084 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg      1854  ipc   50u   REG    0,1        4     0     1033 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg      1854  ipc   52u   REG    0,1        4     0       23 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
gnome-she 1984  ipc   26u   REG    0,1 67108864     0     2054 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
gnome-she 1984  ipc   30r   REG    8,2     4392     0 10224924 /home/ipc/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gnome-she 1984  ipc   34r   REG    8,2    32768     0 10233760 /home/ipc/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-2847cede.log (deleted)
gnome-she 1984  ipc   42u   REG    0,1 67108864     0     2053 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
gsd-media 2184  ipc   13u   REG    0,1 67108864     0     1037 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
gnome-ter 2406  ipc   18u   REG    0,1 67108864     0       24 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
```

So somehow now gnome holds the file? In its name I can still see the hint to pulseaudio.

I tried to truncate the file cia its file descriptor but looking at `/proc/pid-number/fd` I cannot find the FD in question (you can see here that the FD is not a simple number, there is the `u` suffix to it, I do not know what that means).

I have restarted the device multiple times and I also have tried booting with a Ubuntu USB stick and running `fsck -f /dev/sda2`. The command completed with no error messages or warnings.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'll suggest checking you've applied all security fixes & patches if your details are correct; as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS upgraded to 20.04.5 some time ago (refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ for ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded prior to this), and a fully-upgraded system currently reports as 20.04.6 (not 20.04.4 as per your question)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the quick reply. I have upgraded the system, it is now on `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`. But the described problem still exists.